# PHP Recursion -- Increment query variables

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a database where each row contains a unique userid number, and a referralid number that links them to the person that referred them to the site. I am trying to create a recursive function that will search the database as long as it continues to find users, and perform several calculations as it goes. Below is what I have so far - I am getting stuck on trying to create incrementing query variables - PLEASE HELP!

```
function findrepsloop($refidnum, $num){

    echo "FINDREPSLOOP STARTED<br><br>";

    if(strlen($refidnum) > 0){

        echo "FIRST STRLEN IF LOOP PASSED: $refidnum<br><br>";                  
        $totalreps++;   

        $query{$num} = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (refidnum = '$refidnum' && active = 'YES') ";
        $result{$num} = mysql_query($query{$num});
        $line{$num} = mysql_fetch_array($result{$num}, MYSQL_NUM);                  
        $total{$num} = mysql_num_rows($result{$num});

        echo "QUERY $num found $total{$num} rows in the database. LINE 0: '$line{$num}[0]<br><br>";

        $totaltemp = 0;
        if($total{$num} > 2){ $totaltemp = $total{$num} / 3; $totaltemp = floor($totaltemp); }else{}                    
        $numberofthrees = $numberofthrees + $totaltemp;                     

        while(strlen($line{$num}[0]) > 0){

            $refidnum = $line{$num}[0];
            $num++;
            findrepsloop($refidnum, $num);

            $line{$num} = mysql_fetch_array($result{$num}, MYSQL_NUM);
        }

    }else{

    }   

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all the results in the `$line` array? The problem is that it's local to each recursion level. If you want them all to share the same variable, you either have to pass it by reference or use a global variable.

Comment: You really should consider changing your database design.  MySQL doesn't support recursive functions, so it is not well suited to this "adjacency-list" model of representing hierarchical data.  Look into the "nested sets" and "transitive closure table" models instead, either of which will enable you to solve this problem within an instant.  [@BillKarwin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)'s presentation, [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) provides an excellent overview of all the options.

Comment: Here is an example of the code working manually:

  http://pastie.org/private/ozh7pryj5hkgtuk9oe4q